# Iterate over a dictionary and array in python

Tags: python, sql, arrays, json, dictionary

i have an JSON array with names of the columns in database.

```
array = ['id', 'name']
```

I need to make a query with cursor.execute to select these columns and then make a dictionary:

> {firstColumn: firstValue} {secondColumn: secondValue}

```
for column in array:
 cursor.execute("select " + column + " from Database")
```

I don't know how to make a dictionary like this:

> [ {"id":"1","name":"John"}, {"id":"2","name":"Peter"}, etc... ]

Comment: Why would you do a separate query for each column?  Is that actually a requirement?  It would be usual to make a single query for *all* the desired columns at once.

Comment: start by getting all the columns `f"select { ', '.join(array) } from Database;"` That potentially gives you rows back with each row being a list of tuples. You might be able to do `dict(row)` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it in pyodbc. I guess this is what you want:

```
my_list = ["id", "name"]
cursor.execute(f"SELECT {','.join(my_list)} FROM buyers")
result = cursor.fetchall()
my_result_list = [{l:r for l,r in zip(my_list, row)} for row in result]
```

And the results in my case is:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Ana'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'John'},...]
```